# sphinxの検索結果の表示にreStructuredTextがそのまま表示されます

Tags: sphinx

Sphinx1.8.2を使用しています。
検索すると、下記のようにreStructuredTextがそのまま表示されてしまいます。
どのように設定すれば、文字列だけの表示になるのでしょうか？

> 関わりのある情報をまとめてみる 
>   .. include:: ./include_pagebreak.rst ..
>   _useful-dashboard-label: *********************************************************** 関わりのある情報をまとめてみる
>   *********************************************************** メニューの **ダッシュボード** をクリックして表示します。 .....

▼元のreStructuredText

```
.. include:: ./include_pagebreak.rst

.. _useful-dashboard-label:

***********************************************************
関わりのある情報をまとめてみる
***********************************************************

メニューの **ダッシュボード** をクリックして表示します。

.. figure:: ../screenshots/dashboard/dash002.png


.. include:: ./ui_dashboard.rst
```

conf.py の内容（長くなりますが、クライアント名を伏せてすべてを貼り付けます）

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
# Configuration file for the Sphinx documentation builder.
#
# This file does only contain a selection of the most common options. For a
# full list see the documentation:
# http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/config

# -- Path setup --------------------------------------------------------------

# If extensions (or modules to document with autodoc) are in another directory,
# add these directories to sys.path here. If the directory is relative to the
# documentation root, use os.path.abspath to make it absolute, like shown here.
#
# import os
# import sys
# sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))


# -- Project information -----------------------------------------------------

project = 'ユーザーマニュアル'
copyright = '2018, XXX'
author = 'YYY'

# The short X.Y version
version = '1.0.0'
# The full version, including alpha/beta/rc tags
release = '1.0.0'


# -- General configuration ---------------------------------------------------

# If your documentation needs a minimal Sphinx version, state it here.
#
# needs_sphinx = '1.0'

# Add any Sphinx extension module names here, as strings. They can be
# extensions coming with Sphinx (named 'sphinx.ext.*') or your custom
# ones.
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
]

# Add any paths that contain templates here, relative to this directory.
templates_path = ['_templates']

# The suffix(es) of source filenames.
# You can specify multiple suffix as a list of string:
#
# source_suffix = ['.rst', '.md']
source_suffix = '.rst'

# The master toctree document.
master_doc = 'index'

# The language for content autogenerated by Sphinx. Refer to documentation
# for a list of supported languages.
#
# This is also used if you do content translation via gettext catalogs.
# Usually you set "language" from the command line for these cases.
language = 'ja'

# List of patterns, relative to source directory, that match files and
# directories to ignore when looking for source files.
# This pattern also affects html_static_path and html_extra_path.
exclude_patterns = []

# The name of the Pygments (syntax highlighting) style to use.
pygments_style = None


# -- Options for HTML output -------------------------------------------------

# The theme to use for HTML and HTML Help pages.  See the documentation for
# a list of builtin themes.
#
html_theme = 'sphinx_rtd_theme'

# Theme options are theme-specific and customize the look and feel of a theme
# further.  For a list of options available for each theme, see the
# documentation.
#
# html_theme_options = {}

# Add any paths that contain custom static files (such as style sheets) here,
# relative to this directory. They are copied after the builtin static files,
# so a file named "default.css" will overwrite the builtin "default.css".
html_static_path = ['_static']

# Custom sidebar templates, must be a dictionary that maps document names
# to template names.
#
# The default sidebars (for documents that don't match any pattern) are
# defined by theme itself.  Builtin themes are using these templates by
# default: ``['localtoc.html', 'relations.html', 'sourcelink.html',
# 'searchbox.html']``.
#
# html_sidebars = {}

html_search_language = 'ja'
html_show_sourcelink = False
html_scaled_image_link = False
html_style = 'css/my_style.css'
html_logo = '../../XXX_doc/logo/XXX_logow.png'
html_favicon = '../../XXX_doc/logo/XXX_favicon.ico'
html_show_sphinx = False

# -- Options for HTMLHelp output ---------------------------------------------

# Output file base name for HTML help builder.
htmlhelp_basename = 'UserManualdoc'


# -- Options for LaTeX output ------------------------------------------------

latex_elements = {
    # The paper size ('letterpaper' or 'a4paper').
    #
    'papersize': 'a4paper',

    # The font size ('10pt', '11pt' or '12pt').
    #
    # 'pointsize': '10pt',

    # Additional stuff for the LaTeX preamble.
    #
    'preamble': r'''
        \fancypagestyle{normal}{
        \fancyhead[LE,RO]{XXX ユーザーマニュアル}
        \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
        \fancyfoot[LO]{{\rightmark}}
        \fancyfoot[RE]{{\leftmark}}
        \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
        \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
        }
    ''',

    # Latex figure (float) alignment
    #
    'figure_align': 'H',
}

# Grouping the document tree into LaTeX files. List of tuples
# (source start file, target name, title,
#  author, documentclass [howto, manual, or own class]).
latex_documents = [
    (master_doc, 'UserManual.tex', 'XXX ユーザーマニュアル',
     'XX', 'manual'),
]
latex_docclass = {'manual': 'jsbook'}
# latex_additional_files = []

latex_show_pagerefs = True
latex_logo = '../../kbic-kaigi_doc/logo/kbic_logo.png'

# -- Options for manual page output ------------------------------------------

# One entry per manual page. List of tuples
# (source start file, name, description, authors, manual section).
man_pages = [
    (master_doc, 'usermanual', 'User Manual Documentation',
     [author], 1)
]


# -- Options for Texinfo output ----------------------------------------------

# Grouping the document tree into Texinfo files. List of tuples
# (source start file, target name, title, author,
#  dir menu entry, description, category)
texinfo_documents = [
    (master_doc, 'UserManual', 'User Manual Documentation',
     author, 'UserManual', 'One line description of project.',
     'Miscellaneous'),
]


# -- Options for Epub output -------------------------------------------------

# Bibliographic Dublin Core info.
epub_title = project

# The unique identifier of the text. This can be a ISBN number
# or the project homepage.
#
# epub_identifier = ''

# A unique identification for the text.
#
# epub_uid = ''

# A list of files that should not be packed into the epub file.
epub_exclude_files = ['search.html']


# -- Extension configuration -------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: 元のreStructuredTextも一緒に貼り付けてもらえないでしょうか。

Comment: @maya2250 様、元のreStructuredTextと、conf.pyを貼り付けました。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

以下の記事を見つけ、自己解決しました。
https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/1618

reStructuredTextがそのまま表示されるのが普通のようです。
Sphinxの2.0では上記記事の提案が反映されるようですが、現在pipでインストールできるのは1.8.3です。
そこで、上記記事のtextへ変換して置き換える方法を取りました。

1. conf.py に `text_sectionchars = '       '` を追加
2. `sphinx-build -a -b text source build/text` でtextに変換
3. textに変換した結果の`.doctrees`ディレクトリ以外の`.txt`ファイルだけ`build/html/_sources`へコピーする
4. `build/html/_sources`内のファイルの拡張子を`.txt`>`.rst.txt`へ変更する